# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Query Interface, Order parents by most recently created child of each parent

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hey all, I have a model Thread that has_many Posts.

I was wondering with rails3 how i would go about Sorting the thread in descending order by which thread has the most recently created post.

In segments / pseudocode this is what i want to do

for each thread find the most recently created post
somehow combine that post date with its associated post
order my threads by this associated post date in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most perfomance solution here is to use `touch` option:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :thread, :touch => true
end
```

So you will able to find last active Threads as simple as:

```
Thread.order("updated_at DESC").limit(10)
```

What about query... You can try to find it via child objects:

```
active_threads = Post.includes(:threads).order("created_at DESC").all.map(&:thread).uniq
```